# Monitor Apache web server using Java

Tags: apache, webserver, jmx, java

I am in the process of developing a java application that monitors Web Servers and Application servers.

1] To monitor application server metrics like CPU,Memory,Thread and Connection pool i can use JMX API of Java

2] But is there any java api available to monitor Apache Web Servers ?

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this PDF which talks about the different ways to monitor APACHE Web server [PDF Link](http://archive.apachecon.com/na2013/presentations/27-Wednesday/A_Patchy_Web/14:45-Monitoring_Apache_Tomcat.pdf) (Refer to Page number 46)

Answer (score 0):

1) To monitor application server matrix like cpu, memory and all, you can achieve very easily by Unix Scripting..if you are on UNIX Os..

2) Apache itself provide Java api, and again it depends what do you want to monitor ?